# Docker removing Dangling images command not working in CoreOS systemd unit file

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

I want to execute Docker dangling image remove command periodically as a Cron job within my CoreOS instance. But for some reason though the systemd unit timer is successfully executed dangling docker images won't remove. But running the command alone would remove the dangling docker images successfully.

**My Service File** (remove-docker-dangling.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=Removing Docker Dangling Images Cron Service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/docker rmi $(docker images --quiet --filter "dangling=true")
```

**My Timer File** (remove-docker-dangling.timer)

```
[Unit]
Description=Run remove-docker-dangling.service every 30 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/30
```

Comment: 1) This belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser, not StackOverflow.  Good to know for next time.

Comment: 2) Have you tried collecting the output of `journalctl -xe` and `systemctl status remove-docker-dangling`?

Comment: @DerekBrown systemctl status shows Its healthy and active!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main culprit is that `systemd` has limited support for shell-style command parsing ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216780/why-does-bash-parameter-expansion-not-work-inside-systemd-service-files)).  In order for the `$(...)` part to be executed, you need to execute the command in shell:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/bin/docker rmi $(docker images --quiet --filter 'dangling=true')"
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem! Thank for the source as well.